# webgrid view for variable columns

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, webgrid

I am trying to display variable columns in WebGrid in MVC5. Following shows the snippet. However, I am not sure how to render the list of columns and stuck at it.

```css
public class gridmatx
{  public Grid Grid { get; set; }
}
public class Grid
{  public List<string> Columns { get; set; }
    public List<GridRow> Rows { get; set; }
}
public class GridRow
{  public string Label { get; set; }
    public List<decimal> Values { get; set; }
    public List<GridRow> ChildRows { get; set; }
}

//----- controller-------
   public ActionResult Index1()
    {   gridmatx g = new gridmatx();
        g.Grid = new Grid();
        g.Grid.Columns = new List<string> { "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015" };
        g.Grid.Rows = new List<GridRow>
        {   new GridRow { Label = "First", Values = new List<decimal> { 5M, 2M, 1M, 8M, 10M } },
            new GridRow { Label = "Second", Values = new List<decimal> { 2M, 2M, 4M, 8M, 9M } },
            new GridRow { Label = "Third", Values = new List<decimal> { 12M, 8M, 1M, 9M, 3M } }
        };
        return View(g);
   }
```

```html
    var grid = new WebGrid(Model.Grid.Rows, canSort: false, canPage: true, rowsPerPage: 5);
    <div>
        @{ 
            for (int i = 0; i < Model.Grid.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                var index = i;
                @grid.GetHtml(columns:
                 grid.Columns
                 (  grid.Column("Label", "items"),
                     grid.Column(Model.Grid.Rows[i].Values[index], "columnX")
                     ), mode: WebGridPagerModes.Numeric);
            }
```

I have one "label" column and variable number of "Values" columns. 
Appreciate your help in advance.